Is there an Advaitan text which explains the relationship of different aspects of the absolute reality
Is there any explanation of the relationship between Brahman, Ishvara, Atmans, and Prakriti in this world? Obviously, we are all within Nirguna Brahman, but details in regards to these aspects also how can Ishvara have multiple seperate forms?
